# Magento2 get email templates dropdown in stores configuration

Tags: magento2, email-templates

How to get Email Templates in stores configuration in custom Tab. Please find the below link
http://prntscr.com/fvi0og

can anyone help me on this.
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to give like **system.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="paytrade" translate="label" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <group id="general" translate="label" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <field id="paytrade_commission_template" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="3" showInDefault="1" showInStore="1" showInWebsite="1">
                    <label>Test Tab Email Template</label>
                    <comment>Test tab email sent to xyz.</comment>        
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Email\Template</source_model>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

**showInStore="1"** is for show in storeview.

and another file at `/app/code/vendor/modulename/etc/email_templates.xml` have to like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../Email/etc/email_templates.xsd">
    <template id="paytrade_general_paytrade_commission_template" label="Test Tab Email Template" file="test_tab_template_email.html" type="html" module="Ewall_Paytrade" area="frontend"/>
</config>
```

and Create email template file at like: 
`/Ewall/Paytrade/view/frontend/email/test_tab_template_email.html`

Comment: thanks..i think there is no full code in the comment

Comment: I have updated answer

Comment: ok thanks let me try this and get back to you within 2min

Comment: this is showing empty page when code applied

Comment: have you also created file "email_templates.xml" at /app/code/vendor/modulename/etc/email_templates.xml ?

Comment: no i didnot create this file email_templates.xml

Comment: http://prntscr.com/fvi86y actually i renamed the test name tab to ewall and other changes

Comment: I have updated answer with email_templates.xml  file

Comment: ok i will try this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62187/discussion-between-emipro-technologies-pvt-ltd-and-ewall-tester).

Comment: How can we add Multiple email templates in dropdown ? eg: template1.html,template2.html ...

Answer (score 1):

To begin with create a email_templates.xml file in app/code/VendorName/CustomModule/etc folder with the following content.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Email:etc/email_templates.xsd">

<template id="section_id_group_id_field_id" label="Customer Credit Report" file="email_report.html" type="html" module="VendorName_CustomModule" area="frontend"/>

</config>
```

Where template id is the email template identifier and a file with name email_report has got its message in html format. The template identifier will be provided based on the section_id_group_id_field_id which we declare it in the system.xml which will be explained in the following sections.

Create a template file in the path app/code/VendorName/CustomModule/view/frontend/email/email_report.html and the content for email can be added by declaring the template variables from the action file. For instance here the Customer details has been set as a content for email.

```
    {{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}
<!--@subject Custom Email@-->
<!--@vars {
"var data.email":"Sender Email",
"var data.name":"Sender Name"
} @-->
<ul>
<li>
<strong>Customer Details:</strong>
<div>
<p>{{trans “Name:  %name" name=$templateParams.name}}</p>
<p>{{trans “Email:  %Email" Email=$templateParams.email}}</p>
</div>
</li></ul>
{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}
```

The Created email template can be configured from the admin by creating the system.xml file. Add a file system.xml with the following code in the path app/code/VendorName/CustomModule/etc/adminhtml/. This will hold a default value for email template which will be defined in config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
<system>
<section id="section_id" translate="label" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
<group id="group_id" translate="label" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
<field id="field_id" translate="label comment" type="select" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1" canRestore="1">
<label>Label to your field</label>
<source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Email\Template</source_model>
</field>
</group>
</section>
</system>
</config>
```

Create a config.xml file in the path app/code/VendoName/CustomModule/etc/ for setting the default template value in the admin custom field that has been created using system.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
<default>
<section_id>
<group_id>
<field_id>section_id_group_id_field_id</field_id>
</section_id>
</group_id>
</default>
</config>
```

Comment: thanks.. tried this one but iam getting empty page

Comment: in the field_id i have given "paytrade_commission_template" and in the config.xml i kept like this <paytrade_commission_template>custom_email_name</paytrade_commission_template>

Comment: http://prntscr.com/fvi86y

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/183281/send-transactional-email-from-root-folder-magento-2

From this $customEmailPath = 'sales_email/order/template';

I cannot save my custom template for order email so i thought to get from custom path so that it will be like this:
$customEmailPath = 'paytrade_commission/email/template';

Comment: is your section id is paytrade_commission, group id is email and field id is template?

Comment: selection_id is just "paytrade" group id is "general"

Comment: How can we add Multiple email templates in dropdown ? eg: template1.html,template2.html ...