# Magento 2: System.xml configuration shows blank

Tags: magento2, admin, system.xml

I have created system.xml file in my module but it is show me blank

[image]

Path:-`app/code/Amitshree/Customer/etc/adminhtml/system.xml`

Code:-

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <tab id="bliss" translate="label" sortOrder="10">
            <label>bliss</label>
        </tab>
        <section id="cust" translate="label" sortOrder="130" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <class>separator-top</class>
            <label>Customer</label>
            <tab>bliss</tab>
            <resource>Amitshree_Customer::customer_config</resource>
            <group id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                <label>General Configuration</label>
                <field id="your_email_template_field_id" translate="label comment" type="select" sortOrder="2" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Label Of Your Field</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Email\Template</source_model>
                    <!-- This model return all transactional email template list of magento -->
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

Error:-[image]

**app/code/Amitshree/Customer/etc/email_templates.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Email:etc/email_templates.xsd">
    <template id="your_email_template_id" label="Label Of Your Template File" file="your_email_template.html" type="html" module="Amitshree_Customer" area="adminhtml"/>
</config>
<!-- here you define your email template and its template location path-->
```

**app/code/Amitshree/Customer/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../Store/etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
    </default>
</config>
```

Comment: It's showing due to 
this line <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Email\Template</source_model>

Comment: Please follow this answare for same https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/183678/magento2-get-email-templates-dropdown-in-stores-configuration

Comment: which version are you follow mage 2.2.2?

Comment: I tried in Magento 2.1.8 as well in 2.2.2 but not working. If I try any source model except template than it is working perfectly @RakeshJesadiya

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya When i try in magento 2.1.8 it shows blank but when i try in magento 2.2.2 its give an error which i attached in screenshot for now i want to do in magento 2.2.2

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya i am sure that the issue is in <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Email\Template</source_model> and i prefer this link to make this module:- https://webkul.com/blog/magento-2-send-transactional-email-programmatically-in-your-custom-module/

Comment: Could you show your email_templates.xml file?

Comment: I have updated my code @RakeshJesadiya

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya I have uploaded my full module here:- https://goo.gl/pqB1PG

Comment: have you define config.xml? plz show that file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72098/discussion-between-jaimin-and-rakesh-jesadiya).

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: can you please upload config.xml @Piyush

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kindly set your **email_templates.xml** file under **etc** folder with below contents,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Email:etc/email_templates.xsd">
    <template id="cust_general_your_email_template_field_id" label="Label Of Your Template File" file="your_email_template.html" type="html" module="Amitshree_Customer" area="adminhtml"/>
</config>
```

You need to pass your template with id equals to **cust_general_your_email_template_field_id**

**Remove var/generation folder or generated folder from root.**

Comment: how did you know that we have to use cust_general_your_email_template_field_id

Comment: i have faced same error in past and i have resolved it using set template id as error id.

Comment: ok means i have to refer sections and group ids  of system.xml right?

Comment: no you just set inside email_templates.xml file. Just try using delete var and generated folder

Comment: yes it is working. :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace your source model with this

```
<source_model>Amitshree\Customer\Model\Config\Source\Email\Template</source_model>
```

and create **Template.php** at

> app/code/Amitshree/Customer/Model/Config/Source/Email/Template.php

```
<?php

namespace Amitshree\Customer\Model\Config\Source\Email;

class Template extends \Magento\Framework\DataObject implements \Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface
{

    private $_coreRegistry;

    private $_emailConfig;

    protected $_templatesFactory;


    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
        \Magento\Email\Model\ResourceModel\Template\CollectionFactory $templatesFactory,
        \Magento\Email\Model\Template\Config $emailConfig,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($data);
        $this->_coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
        $this->_templatesFactory = $templatesFactory;
        $this->_emailConfig = $emailConfig;
    }

    /**
     * Generate list of email templates
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        /** @var $collection \Magento\Email\Model\ResourceModel\Template\Collection */
        if (!($collection = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('config_system_email_template'))) {
            $collection = $this->_templatesFactory->create();
            $collection->load();
            $this->_coreRegistry->register('config_system_email_template', $collection);
        }
        return $options;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:-

```
        <section id="cust" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="130" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">            
            <label>Customer</label>
            <tab>bliss</tab>
            <resource>Amitshree_Customer::customer_config</resource>
            <group id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                <label>General Configuration</label>
                <field id="your_email_template_field_id" translate="label comment" type="select" sortOrder="2" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Label Of Your Field</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Email\Template</source_model>
                    <!-- This model return all transactional email template list of magento -->
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
```